# How to modify imagePickerController (source camera) not to dismiss after pressing "Use photo" until 4 photos are taken?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to take 4 photos before UIImagePickerController is dismissed. How to modify it?
I have following button action and delegate:

```
@IBAction func take4Photos(_ sender: Any) {
                if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
                    let image = UIImagePickerController()
                    image.delegate = self
                    image.sourceType = .camera;
                    image.allowsEditing = false
                    self.present(image, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    
                }
            }


func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage{
       
        imagePicked = image
       
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will recommend you to use `ImagePicker`, which can be easily installed through cocoaPods and it can fulfill your requirement with just one line of Code.

```
let imagePickerController = ImagePickerController()
imagePickerController.imageLimit = 4
```

You can check `ImagePicker` library [here](https://github.com/hyperoslo/ImagePicker)

Here's how you can use `ImagePicker` library to pick multiple images.

Create a button in Storyboard and have its outlet in the ViewController.

```
@IBOutlet weak var chooseImage: UIButton!
```

If you want to see the selected images in VC after selection, make an array of `UIImages` like this

```
var imageViews:[UIImageView] = []
```

Then, in `viewDidLoad`, add target to `chooseImage` button

```
chooseImage.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTouched(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

And declare `buttonTouched` function outside the `viewDidLoad` like this

```
  @objc func buttonTouched(button: UIButton) {
  let config = Configuration()
  config.doneButtonTitle = "Done"
  config.noImagesTitle = "Sorry! There are no images here!"
  config.recordLocation = false 
  config.allowVideoSelection = false. //If you don't want video recording

  let imagePicker = ImagePickerController(configuration: config)
  imagePicker.delegate = self

  present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Then, in the end, inside the `extension`, conform to `ImagePicker` delegate functions like this.

```
extension OwnerAddListingFacilitiesViewController:ImagePickerDelegate {

 func cancelButtonDidPress(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController) {
    
    imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }


 func wrapperDidPress(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController, images: [UIImage]) { //Don't know what exactly this function does }

 func doneButtonDidPress(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController, images: [UIImage]) {
    for Count in 0..<images.count {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: images[Count])
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: (0 * (110 * Count)), y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
        imageViews.append(imageView)
    }
    
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

 }
```

You'll be able to see small thumbnail like images after selecting them and pressing done.

Comment: Hi, I installed  ```pod 'ImagePicker'``` by cocoa pods but for some reason there is no ImagePickerDelegate available in my VC (it is declared in the Pods though) .. any tips?:)

Comment: Hi, when I do your steps I get 3 warnings 1)Use of unresolved identifier Configuration 2)Use of... ImagePickerController and 3) Use of undeclared type OwnerAddListingFacilitiesViewController ... as I said before, for some reasons methods from ImagePicker are not available, don't know why

Comment: @Eljer, did you imported 'ImagePicker' pod inside your file? Write `import ImagePicker` at the top of you ViewController. And for the third error you mentioned, that's becuase `OwnerAddListingFacilitiesViewController` is name of my ViewController file which I am using here in my code personally. You have to mention the name of your viewController here.

Comment: Perfect! It is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that is not possible. UIImagePickerController can pick only one media. If you want that behaviour, either you have to create your own picker or use a library.

If you want to create your own, use this resource
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/browsing_and_modifying_photo_albums

It has an official demo source from which you can create your own within 2-3 hours (I had to do this exact problem once, multiple image and video selection from a grid like selector)